# Reformatting numbers to date in excel

Tags: excel, date, reformatting

I have an excel sheet with over 6000 rows and each row has a cell with the date in it. Unfortunately, the date is formatted as a number like "20000515" would be 05-15-2000. When I go into the cell and add the dashes to make it "2000-05-15" it formats correctly however I do not want to go through in each individual cell and make this change. I have tried going under the "number" section in the Home tab to try and reformat, and I have also tried recording a macro. I may do doing this wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Formula: `=--TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00")` and copy down the dataset.

Comment: I just had to do in another column instead of the same, that should be fine, thank you.

Comment: That formats it to the way i would like it to look (or similar) but excel still doesn't recognize it as a date. When I go to graph it still doesn't like it.

Comment: did you include the `--` in the formula?

Comment: I did not, however when I add the -- for a cell with the date 20000103 (01/03/2000) it spits out 36528

Comment: That is the true form of that date, now format the cell as desired.  Dates to excel are the number of days since 12/31/1899 formatted as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much